# Filtrar coluna por string especifica

Tags: python, string, pandas

Estou tentando realizar um filtro no meu dataframe (`df_movies_usa`) para eliminar todos os outros tipos de moeda que não sejam representadas por "**$**". A moeda esta na coluna `df_movies_usa["budget"]`.

Estou utilizando o seguinte codigo:

```
import pandas as pd
df_movies = pd.read_csv("IMDb movies.csv", sep = ",")
df_movies["country"] = df_movies["country"].str.replace("UK, USA", "USA")
df_movies["country"] = df_movies["country"].str.replace("USA, Canada", "USA")
df_movies["country"] = df_movies["country"].str.replace("Canada, USA", "USA")
df_movies["country"] = df_movies["country"].str.replace("USA, Germany", "USA")
df_movies_usa = df_movies[df_movies['country'] == "USA"]
df_movies_usa = df_movies_usa[df_movies_usa["budget"].str.contains("$")]
```

Porém no dataframe ainda contem todas as linhas com outros tipos de moeda (por ex GBP, RUR)

Comment: Consegue postar o código para que possamos fazer os devidos testes e tentar te ajudar?

Comment: Codigo alterado!

Comment: Não houve alteração de código, apenas a que fiz adicionando o `BB Code`...

Comment: Sou novo aqui, quando vc diz para postar o codigo, vc quer que eu anexe em extensão ipynb o notebook aqui?

Comment: Você tem mais partes além do que postou, certo? Nós precisamos do máximo de informação possível para poder simular o seu erro e tentar te ajudar, com isso, sem o código, apenas com a parte que está dando erro, não conseguimos te ajudar.

Comment: Fiz a edição da pergunta contendo todo o codigo

Comment: Consegue dar um `var_dump(df_movies_usa[df_movies_usa["budget"])` e postar o resultado?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na documentação, acho que isto daqui pode te ajudar e muito: [Documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: KeyError: "None of [Index([' 45000', ' 5700', ' 23500', ' 40000', ' 25000', ' 20000', ' 10000',\n       ' 50000', ' 17022', ' 50000',\n       ...\n       ' 5000000', ' 1500000', ' 130000', ' 95000', ' 1000', ' 100000',\n       ' 1500000', ' 3000000', ' 7000', ' 500000'],\n      dtype='object', length=11132)] are in the [columns]"

Answer (score 1):

Estás a usar o método contains com o símbolo `$` o que o pandas interpreta como `regex`. Experimenta adicionar `regex=false`:

```
df_movies_usa = df_movies_usa[df_movies_usa["budget"].str.contains("$", regex=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe bem o uso do método `contains`, esse método retornará todos os resultados que contém o elemento filtrado, ou seja, no seu caso, todas as ocorrências de `$`, pode ser só o `$`, pode ser `R$`, ou outra moeda que possui cifrão.

Você pode realizar a filtragem com o método equal (`eq`) que retornará dentro do teu dataframe apenas os correspondentes igualitários.

De uma olhada nessa documentação:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html